# jQuery global play and pause for HTML5 audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, playback

I've got a page full of HTML5 audio tags, each of which can toggle between play and pause, and only one can play at a time. I'm working on a set of global controls that will play/pause whatever is active, scan to beginning or previous track, and next track. If you have any ideas or solutions that can help me solve all of those please speak up :)

Regarding the global audio, I've botched together what I consider theoretically feasible, but am not getting any results. No errors via Firebug... Not sure where to go from here.

Your advice is much appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div id="global"></div>    
<div id="music_right">
            <div class="thumbnail" id="paparazzi">
                <a class="playback">
                    <img class="play" src="../images/icons/play.png" />
                </a>
                <audio>
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_paparazzisnlmix.wav" type="audio/x-wav" />
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail" id="danceinthedark">
                <a class="playback">
                    <img class="play" src="../images/icons/play.png" />
                </a>
                <audio>
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_danceinthedark.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_danceinthedark.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_danceinthedark.wav" type="audio/x-wav" />
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
                </audio>
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail" id="bornthisway">
                <a class="playback">
                    <img class="play" src="../images/icons/play.png" />
                </a>
                <audio>
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_bornthisway.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_bornthisway.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
                    <source src="../audio/fernando_garibay_bornthisway.wav" type="audio/x-wav" />
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
                </audio>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
//global play/pause

        $('#global').click(function(){
        var song = $('audio');
        if(song.paused){
            song.play();
         } else {
             song.pause();
         }
    });
    //audio tag play/pause
        var curPlaying;
        $(function() {
            $(".playback").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var song = $(this).next('audio')[0];
                if(song.paused){
                    song.play();
                    if(curPlaying) $("audio", "#"+curPlaying)[0].pause();
                } else {
                    song.pause();
                    }
                curPlaying = $(this).parent()[0].id;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be looking for a plugin, but this one is really great. It also will play the audio on a mobile device.

http://www.jplayer.org/

Quick Demo I made a while back.
http://sethaldridge.com/demos/

Answer (score 3):

I helped you out on a different question for this project yesterday I think.

You should change your click handler for the `global` div like so:

```
$('#global').click(function(){
    $('audio').each(function() {
      var song = $(this);
      if(song.paused){
        song.play();
       } else {
         song.pause();
       }
     });
});
```

When you do something like `var song = $("audio");` the song variable ends up representing a collection of all the `<audio>` elements on the page and that's why it doesn't work when you check `song.paused` because you're not dealing with an individual audio element at that point.

Comment: you did! Thank you for then and thank you for now. I learn a little bit each time.

I understand what you did here.. makes much more sense than what I posted. In context of the page, though, I still don't get any action out of it. There's no pause or resume that is.. Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/danielredwood/FTfSq/11/